# alternation of quantifiers in the language of PA

Tags: logic

Is there a natural (I mean easily definable in the ordinary language) sequence of sentences in the signature of PA in the prefix normal form with increasing complexity of the prefixes, but any element in this sequence is not equivalent to one with a shorter prefix ?

Comment: "Natural" is going to be very hard here. We can't use any provable or refutable formula, because such a formula is equivalent (under PA) to either $0=0$ or $0=1$. So they all have to be undecidable, and there's a distinct paucity of **"natural"** formulas that are known to be undecidable in PA.

Comment: and what about a few concrete examples having prefix length, say $n=0,1,2$ and $3$--is there a reference for these?B.t.w what is the prefix length of the sentence equivalent to induction in PA?

Comment: @user122424 What do you mean "the sentence equivalent to induction"? Induction in $PA$ isn't a single axiom, and indeed for this reason $PA$ is not finitely axiomatizable!

Comment: @user122424 As to examples of small prefix length, **Goodstein's Theorem** is $\Pi_2$ and the consistency of $PA$ itself is $\Pi_1$.

Comment: And already for $3$ no example except $2$-consistency?

Comment: @user122424 Not to the best of my knowledge. Again, if you look at **formulas** instead of **sentences** then things get much more interesting, but for sentences the landscape is pretty sparse.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that $\varphi_n$="$PA$ is $n$-consistent" is expressible by a (if I recall correctly) $\Pi_{n+1}$-sentence for each $n$, but not by a sentence of lower complexity, so $\{\varphi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ gives an example. Of course the sticking point is whether these are natural, but I think they are - they come up quite naturally in [proof theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.02857.pdf).

(Recall that "$PA$ is $n$-consistent" means "Every $\Sigma_n$ consequence of $PA$ is true.")

---

At the level of *formulas* instead of *sentences*, there are standard formulas $\psi_n$ defining the set $0^{(n)}$ (the $n$th iterate of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), with $\psi_n$ properly $\Sigma_n$.

Comment: Yes, I'm apparently blind.